# How to launch a python script in a virtual environment from a C++ program on Windows?

Tags: python, c++, windows, process, virtualenv

So far I am using a 2-step approach and launch `cmd.exe` rather than `python.exe`. But I don't like `cmd.exe` in between the process tree for several reasons (e.g. I don't receive the python process handle or ID, but rather the one of `cmd.exe`).

```
string sCmd =
  "cmd.exe /C venv\\SomeEnv\\Scripts\\activate.bat && python.exe Subprograms\\my_script.py";
CreateProcessA(nullptr,
  sCmd.data(),
  ...);
```

I believe that to activate the virtual environment I need to put it at the beginning of the `PATH` environment variable and set some other variables like `PYTHONHOME` and `PYTHONPATH`, but I'm not sure whether this is sufficient and what values to set there on Windows.

Comment: You don't need to activate the environment, you just need to run that specific python.exe. For example, `C:\\venv\\SomeEnv\\Bin\\python.exe Subprograms\\my_script.py`.

Comment: If the py launcher is installed and associated with .py files (default installation), then just add a shebang to "my_script.py", such as `#!C:\path\to\venv\SomeEnv\Scripts\python.exe`. Then "my_script.py" will be executable via `ShellExecuteW`, via configuration that's local to the script itself, without having to hard code the interpreter path to use *everywhere* that you want to run the script.

Comment: @Sraw, venv virtual environments in Windows use a "Scripts" folder instead of the Unix "bin" directory.

Answer (score -2):

```
If you want to do it using standard C++, you can go for std::system()

std::system("command_to_run_with_space_separated_params_if_any");

If you want to use windows ways, you can go for followings...
  ShellExecuteEx()
  ShellExecute()
  CreateProcessA()
  CreateProcessW()
```